# Select x value within a text - string_to_array

Tags: arrays, string, postgresql, select

I have a column in **table1** that contains names separated with commas, like a,b,c

| names | result |
| --- | --- |
| a,d,e |  |
| a,c,e,f |  |
| c,d,f,g |  |

Another column with a single name in **table2**, like a or b or c

| line | name | origin |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | US |
| 2 | b | UK |
| 3 | c | UK |
| 4 | d | AUS |
| 5 | e | CAN |
| 6 | f | UK |
| 7 | g | UK |

And I want to update table1.result if any names from table1.names are in table2.name & origin = UK.

Tried this, but getting error;

```
update table1 as t1
set result = 
(select name from table2 where origin='UK') = any(string_to_array(t1.names, ','))
```

Comment: Can you update your post with the expected output table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `exists(...)` if the result you want is boolean:

```sql
update table1 as t1
set result = exists(
    select name 
    from table2 
    where origin = 'UK'
    and name = any(string_to_array(t1.names, ','))
    );
```

Test it in [db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/C9Fg_rus)

If you want to get the names, use `string_agg()`:

```sql
update table1 as t1
set result = (
    select string_agg(name, ',') 
    from table2 
    where origin = 'UK'
    and name = any(string_to_array(t1.names, ','))
    );
```

[Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/pWxiaU70)